# Angular 2 RC 1 correct way to get element style

Tags: angular

Since in RC 1 we can't access the DomAdapter (DOM, BrowserDomAdapter, ...) and the Ruler service has been removed from API (https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8452) , what is the correct way to get the bounding rect for an element in Angular 2 directives?

I know I can use nativeElement, but this is not recommended because it will not work in a Web Worker...

Thank you

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8509